# Case when logic for datetime in redshift

Tags: datetime, amazon-redshift, case

I have a datetime column in my table, and I want to create a new column where explains the maximum date with a case when syntax.

The table is look like this:

```
schedule                 
11 April,2023, 13:00
11 April,2023, 14:00
11 April, 2023, 17:00
```

If the time is more than 17:00 then the maximum date will be on the next day, and if the time is less than 17:00 then maximum date will be on the same day at 23:59.

The expected results:

```
schedule                  max_date        
11 April,2023, 13:00      11 April, 2023, 23:59
11 April,2023, 14:00      11 April, 2023, 23:59
11 April, 2023, 17:00     12 April, 2023, 17:00
```

So far, what I have done is:

```
select
    schedule,
    case when extract(hour from schedule) >= 17 then schedule + 1 else (missing query) end as max_date
from data
```

I am lost to continue the query when the schedule hour is less than 17. The max_date should be on the same day but the hour is at 24:00

How can I get the expected result in the max_date column in redshift?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

11 April, 2023, 24:00 is actually (and properly) 12 April, 2023, 00:00.   So you could just add one day to "schedule" and truncate to the day.

Also, "schedule + 1" is ambiguous so I would clear this up by changing it to "schedule + interval '1 day'".

Putting these together:

```
select
    schedule,
    case when extract(hour from schedule) >= 17 then schedule + interval '1 day' 
         else trunc(schedule)::timestamp + interval '1 day'
      end as max_date
from data;
```

=======================================

To get 23:59 you just need to subtract a minute (or a second or a millisecond or ...)

```
select
    schedule,
    case when extract(hour from schedule) >= 17 then schedule + interval '1 day' 
         else trunc(schedule)::timestamp + interval '1 day' - interval '1 minute'
      end as max_date
from data;
```

Comment: thank you for your help! Sorry for the ambiguity, but 11 April, 2023, 24:00 should be 11 April, 2023, 23:59. If the hour is less than 17:00 then the max_date would be on the same day but the hour is at 23:59. What would be the query look like? Thanks!